# Find missing/moved video clip Kdenlive

Tags: kdenlive

After moving a video clip used by kdenlive from one folder to another, kdenlive can no longer find the video clip and tells me "missing clip".

How do I tell kdenlive where the new location of the video clip is? Or do I have to delete the missing clip, add it back in, then re-add all of the crops/transitions/effects back onto the track?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I've found to fix this is to save my project, close KDEnlive, then relaunch and open the project.  KDEnlive will pop up a box with all the missing clips and give you the option to search recursively to find them.

Once it finds each clips' new folder, click "OK".

Be sure to save your project again after KDEnlive has made the changes.

(aside: would be nice if KDEnlive had an option to perform this recursive search when right-clicking a clip that has gone "missing"... maybe someday)

Comment: This worked for me. The dialog lets you search recursively for any missing file(s), so select a common parent directory. For me it hung after doing this, but I killed it (with `xkill`) and then restarted it, reloaded the project, said that yes I did want to recover the project, and all is well once again.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to leave the clip in its new location and still have kdenlive see it, while preserving your edits, would be to symlink it.  In the terminal `cd` to the folder where it used to be. Then, enter:

```
ln -s path-to-clip's-new-location clip's-filename
```

For example, if the clip were named `clip.avi` and your username were `dave` and the clip now resided in the `Videos` subfolder of your home folder, then the command would be, after changing into the directory where kdenlive expects the clip to be:

```
ln -s /home/dave/Videos/clip.avi clip.avi
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, not the most elegant, yet quite efficient way to re-map data location to your KDEnlive file is just open the project file (which is *.kdenlive) in text editor and manually replace required pieces of paths by mask. I.e. you moved your data from

'/home/video/prj'

to

'home/video/prj/1'

So everywhere mask '/home/video/prj' is found, it must be replaced with 'home/video/prj/1'. When you complete all changes, just save the file and that's it. It opens in KDEnlive with whole new mapped paths to your data.